# Video Editors Supporting 5.1 Surround Sound?

Tags: audio-quality

Now that I've found a way to record in surround sound I'd like to keep surround intact while editing the files. Features I need include trimming, appending, and adding narration to paused frames.

Ease of use and cost (less than $100) are my primary concerns. There is no need for special effects or advanced transitions.

So far I've tried Windows Movie Maker and Vegas Movie Studio Platinum. The latter looks promising, but it won't detect the audio in my 5.1 channel video files. (Windows Media Player does play the files back in surround sound.)

EDIT: For reference, Windows lists the audio in the files as 4608kbps, 6 channel, and 48kHz.

Comment: I would suspect any full featured video editor can take in as many audio channels as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Davinci Resolve 14 would definitely do this as it has all new audio, otherwise Adobe Premier will work

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Still, $300 is a steep price especially when there is no trial or demo version to test first.

Comment: Davinci resolve is free and a paid version. Both are the same but the paid version has more pro features. Adobe premier has a 30 day trail and then it is a monthly subscription. The only one I know which costs $300 is FCPX which i didn't recommend as you are running windows but again that does have a trail of you are on a Mac

Comment: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/davinciresolve/#

Comment: https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/premiere

Comment: Davinci Resolve does indeed have a free version. I hadn't read far enough. Sadly it won't import my videos at all, it just silently fails.